# What does self do in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm on railcasts just practicing some rails and have come across something I'm trying to understand.

I didn't get what the "self" on the authenticate method was doing. So I deleted it and tested the login of my app to see if it would show an error and it did:

```
error:

**NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `authenticate' for #<Class:0x00000102cb9000**>
```

I would really appreciate if someone could explain exactly what that "Self" is doing. I was trying to figure out exactly what was going on but can't get my head around it.

Method is defined in model and called in sessions_controller..
I've been continuously deleting my app and starting from scratch to get the hang of it and many things make sense to me each time i start again but I'm stuck at "self".

I'm just the type of person who likes to understand why something works.

controller:

```
 def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged In"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid credentials"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

model:

```
 def self.authenticate(email, password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash ==  BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a basic ruby question. In this case, `self` is used to define a class method.

```
    class MyClass
      def instance_method
        puts "instance method"
      end

      def self.class_method
        puts "class method"
      end
    end
```

Which are used like this:

```
    instance = MyClass.new
    instance.instance_method
```

Or:

```
    MyClass.class_method
```

Hope that clears things up a little bit. Also refer to: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: Slight extension to your answer: `def object.my_foo_method`. Defines `my_foo_method` on `obj`. In the context of your answer, `self` is the object of class `Class` (namely, the class `MyClass`). Hence, it defines the method on that class.

Comment: Shouldn't an `@` sign be used for instances, e.g. @instance = ... ?

Comment: given that it's rails and that will probably be used in the view

Answer (score 5):

`self` defines a method of the **class** instead of the **instance** of the class. So with `def self.authenticate` you can do the following:

```
u = User.authenticate('email@domain.com','p@ss')
```

Instead of doing…

```
u = User.new
u.authenticate('email@domain.com','p@ss')
```

That way, you don't have to create an instance of user to authenticate one.

Comment: Other than to avoid needing to instantiate a class in order to use a method, are there other reasons to define class methods instead of instance methods?

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completion and to thwart future headaches, I'd like to also point out that the two are equivalent:

```
class User
  def self.authenticate
  end
end

class User
  def User.authenticate
  end
end
```

Matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

```
class User
    def self.xxx 
    end
end
```

is one way of defining class method while

```
class User    
    def xxx 
    end
end
```

will define an instance method.

If you remove the self. from the def, you will get a method not found error when you do

```
User.authenticate
```

because you are trying to call a method on a class rather than an instance of the class.  To use an instance method, you need an instance of a class.